# Arabic text displayed as Ø§Ù„Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù on webpage also when retrieved in android app

Tags: php, mysql, text, character, arabic

I created a mysql database. i have set characters to utf-8 and collation to utf8_general_ci. In database table the text is okay. But when i view it on webpage it looks like this "Ø§Ù„Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù". When i retrieve this code to my android app i am having the same problem.

**php code (index.php)**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.ph", "db_name", "passwrd", "u242667358_test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
```

**php code (index.php)**

```
require_once('db.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM BalochiNames ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";   

mysqli_query($con, $query); 

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo stripslashes($row['BalochiName']);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Please avoid sharing the actual credentials.

Comment: dude your host passwords hide it quick

Comment: And change them! The history on this question will remain!

Comment: Database connection and table charset is only half the answer. Also ensure HTML page encoding matches. (See the reference for more details.)

Comment: lol ok thanks @buddi

Comment: ok thanks @golezTrol i will

Comment: [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)